# JetPack file is deleted continously

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I’ve encountered a strange issue with jetpack. After installing Jetpack, my page returns 500, and error_log says that class-waf-trasnforms.php is missing. Here is the log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/wpstage/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack_vendor/automattic/jetpack-waf/src/class-waf-transforms.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php82/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/wpstage/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/vendor/jetpack-autoloader/class-php-autoloader.php:90
```

I’m confused because when I put that file manually via ftp, the file is deleted somehow after a couple of seconds. Removing jetpack from plugins helps but after reinstalling jetpack problem still occurs